# Past Perfect and conjunction "till"

Tags: past-perfect, clauses

Being given a task to unite different sentences into one by using conjunctions, I faced a little question to be answered.

> The man didn't leave. He didn't receive a definite answer. (till)

My variant was:

> The man hadn't left till he received a definite answer.

The key says:

> The man didn't leave till he had received a definite answer.

I don't know why, but I think the second variant is better. I have run out of good ideas why, though. I can assume that it is a time clause (as we we said about future: `"don't say nothing until you've done it"`), may be that is the only one matter. He didn't leave - is previous, later one (receiving) happened after it.

Comment: Try "The man didn't leave till he received a definite answer."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that it's about time.  The tenses of hadn't and till don't agree.  Till means *up to the present time* while hadn't is past tense.

Till is a shortening of until.  (I don't understand how that came about, I prefer to use 'til, even though it's wrong and till is considered correct.)

However, I take issue with this exercise because the answer has a different meaning from the question.  In the question, the man never left and never got a definite answer.  In the solution, the man did get a definite answer and then he left.  Perhaps you shouldn't take too much stock in this exercise.